# JSON Replace Text with variable

Tags: json, regex, file, variables, replace

I have a JSON File in which are Dateobjects. I want to replace them with Formated Date Strings. Can somebody give me a hint how it would be possible in an easy way?

In the JSON File there are lines like:

> "insertedAt": {       "$date": "2018-01-31T11:05:39.447Z"     },

I want to replace them with:

> "insertedAt": "2018-01-31 11:05:39.447000"

The files are pretty big so I would like to avoid loading them into JSON-Objects and solve it with regex replacement or something similar. Unfortunatly I am not really experienced with it.

Is it possible to replace something with a function output of itself?
I can select the parts that I want to replace with the regex:

```
"insertedAt":{".*"}
```

Can I now replace it with a function of *? In Pseudocode it would be like:

```
replace("\"insertedAt\":{\".*\"}").with("\"insertedAt\":" + format(*))
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `lookbehind` in your `regex engine`, then you can try this for matching target string

```
(?<=insertedAT\": )\{ \"\$date\": (\"[^\"]*\") \},
```

and replace it with capture `group 1` ( `\1` or `$1`). [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/138)

Or, if you can't use `lookbehind` in your `regex engine`, then you can try this `regex`,

```
(?!insertedAT\": )\{ \"\$date\": (\"[^\"]*\") \},
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/139)